# Allegro common lisp in-package does not work

Tags: common-lisp

I need help in understanding why Allegro CL does not execute the in-package directive put in loaded file. More precisely I load the LISA environment and would like to make Lisa the active package, but after loading the lisp file with the directive the prompt continues to be CL-USER-

Comment: You can define a "setup" function that sets the current package to Lisa package, but you need to call it after loading the files (in a startup script for example)

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behavior.

From CLHS documentation of [`LOAD`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_load.htm)

> `load` binds `*readtable*` and `*package*` to the values they held before loading the file.

So any reassignments to `*package*` made while loading a file are discarded.

This allows `IN-PACKAGE` to be used within the file to specify how the code in that file is processed, without having side effects on the user's environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Barmar, for your answer. After the file are loaded I will launch a top-level in-package command.